# combining rows, NA R

Tags: r, rows, na

I have the following dataframe below. I would like to convert it to the second dataframe.

```
Currently Have:

CITY0   ST0   Zip0   Lat0   Long0    CITY1     ST1     Zip1     ID   Volume
NA      NA    NA     0.00   0.00     Boston    MA      02101    X1   2
Boston  MA    02102  42     -71      NA        NA      NA       X1   2


Would like:

CITY0  ST0  Zip0     Lat0   Long0    CITY1    ST1     Zip1     ID    Volume
Boston MA   02102    42     -71      Boston   MA      02101    X1    2
```

Would like the solution in R...thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate_all(function(x) x[!is.na(x) & x != 0]) %>%
    slice(1)
## A tibble: 1 x 10
## Groups:   ID [1]
#  CITY0  ST0    Zip0  Lat0 Long0 CITY1  ST1    Zip1 ID    Volume
#  <chr>  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <int> <chr>  <int>
#1 Boston MA     2102   42.  -71. Boston MA     2101 X1         2
```

Explanation: We group by `ID`, and replace every column with entries that are non-`NA` and non-zero. Collapse with slicing the first row.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "CITY0   ST0   Zip0   Lat0   Long0    CITY1     ST1     Zip1     ID   Volume
NA      NA    NA     0.00   0.00     Boston    MA      02101    X1   2
Boston  MA    02102  42     -71      NA        NA      NA       X1   2", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

```
# df is your data frame

# option 1    
df = df[!is.na(df$CITY0),]

# option 2
df = df[complete.cases(df$b),]
```